# Convert a list of strings to a list of symbols that represent variables

Tags: r, xts

I have a list of strings that represent xts object names in the global environment. How can i convert the list of strings into a list of names to be formatted properly to insert into a do.call function? That way the function merges the xts objects, rather than just the names of strings.

```
xtsNames <- list("name1", "name2", "name3")

name1 <- xts(x=1:10, order.by=Sys.Date()-1:10)
name2 <- xts(x=11:20, order.by=Sys.Date()-11:20)
name3 <- xts(x=21:30, order.by=Sys.Date()-21:30)


as.name(xtsNames) # this code fails because it does not work on a list

NewData <- do.call(rbind, xtsNames) # this code merges the strings, rather 
                                    # than the xts objects
```

Comment: On a sidenote: in these cases it makes a lot more sense to actually have name1, name2 and name3 object as elements of a list. That keeps them together and makes it quite a bit easier to then do `do.call(rbind, thatlist)`.

Comment: @ Joris, are you saying to convert the sting list into a name list before passing to do.call?

Comment: No I'm saying that you should have a `mylist <- list(name1, name2, name3)` so you can do `do.call(rbind, mylist)`. Obviously this doesn't help when you start from individual objects. But you shouldn't have to start from individual objects. Keeping things that belong together in lists makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I completely understood your question, but you may want to use 'get' over here.

```
do.call('rbind',lapply(xtsNames, get))
```

**On a side note**: To understand 'get', suppose x <- 2, then if you pass, get('x') on the console, you will get 2 as value returned.

**?get:**

> Search by name for an object (get) or zero or more objects (mget).

This will return some of the rows like below:

```
> do.call('rbind',lapply(xtsNames, get))
           [,1]
2018-09-27   30
2018-09-28   29
2018-09-29   28
2018-09-30   27
2018-10-01   26
2018-10-02   25
2018-10-03   24
```

Comment: thanks very much, i need to understand the ways to use lapply better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `rlang` package to convert strings of variable names to actual symbols:

```
do.call( rbind, rlang::syms(xtsNames) )
```

If you want just base R, then it can be done using `lapply`:

```
do.call( rbind, lapply(xtsNames, as.name) )
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend using the base solution, considering `rlang` is in a state of flux and the benefit of using it over the base solution is minimal in this case.

Comment: @Artem, it is also a great solution. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @Joshua. [syms() is considered stable at this point](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/lifecycle.html), but I agree that it's additional features are probably unnecessary in this case.